# jQuery - Do something as soon as input value reaches certain length

Tags: javascript, jquery, input

So I have an input field where someone would put in a year. I want to have jQuery fade in a div AS SOON as the input value length = 4. Or in other words, as soon as the input reaches its max length.

The below works but you have to click outside of the input box once you fill it with 4 characters, in order to see the div fade in. How can I make jQuery almost watch the input and do something as soon as the maxlength is reached?

HTML:

```
<input type="text" id="year" placeholder="YYYY" maxlength="4" size="4">
```

jQuery:

```
$("#year").change(function () {

     if ($(this).val().length === 4 ) {

         $("div").fadeIn("slow");

     }
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you need to listen to the keyup event. The keyup event is sent to an element when the user releases a key on the keyboard.  the change event triggers when the input looses complete focus

```
$("#year").keyup(function () {

     if ($(this).val().length === 4 ) {

         $("div").fadeIn("slow");

     }
});
```